# Need some help for radio button change function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

http://keralapsctuts.com/Old/topic.php?id=14

The above is the page I am working on but I have a problem. After loading all my questions and choices from by MySQL database, I would like to have a feature whereby the user selects a choice, it checks to see if answer is correct or not, then if the selection is correct the text changes to green or red (if incorrect selection).

This is the layout of a typical question/choice:

```
'<div class="question_container">
    <p class="questions">'.$question.'</p>
    <span class="group">
        <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans1.'" />'.$ans1.'
        <input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans2.'" />'.$ans2.'
        <input id="id_radio3" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans3.'" />'.$ans3.'
        <input id="id_radio4" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans4.'" />'.$ans4.'
    </span>
</div>';
```

Comment: You should provide _a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_ of code in question.

Comment: pass all the information to javascript. `json_encode` is a handy php function you might need.

Comment: @Regent 
<div class="question_container"><p class="questions">'.$question.'</p>
    <span class="group">
                   <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans1.'" />'.$ans1.'
                   <input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans2.'" />'.$ans2.'
                   <input id="id_radio3" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans3.'" />'.$ans3.'
                   <input id="id_radio4" type="radio" name="group'.$id.'" value="'.$ans4.'" />'.$ans4.'
    </span></div>';
      }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814369/getting-radio-button-value-and-sending-through-ajax-to-php

Comment: Not clear explaination..

Comment: @Raj You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then consider either revamping your question or asking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really give enough info, but this may be similar to what you are looking for:

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9fodp62k/)

**Question/Answer Block:**

```
<div class="question_container">
    <p class="questions">Question about stuff?</p>
    <span class="group" style="inline-block;">
        <label>
            <input id="id_radio1" class="incorrect" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 1" />Answer 1
        </label>
        <label>
            <input id="id_radio2" class="correct" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 2" />Answer 2
        </label>
        <label>
            <input id="id_radio3" class="incorrect" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 3" />Answer 3
        </label>
        <label>
            <input id="id_radio4" class="incorrect" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 4" />Answer 4
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    var Radio       =   $(this);
    var GetGroup    =   Radio.parents(".group");
    GetGroup.find("label").css({"background-color":"transparent"});
    // You can use a one-line ternary here to switch colors
    Radio.parent().css({"background-color":((Radio.attr("class") == 'correct')? "green" : "red")});
});
```

Comment: you are a champ, May i ask you one more thing. Is it possible to show and hide a div also.

Comment: Yes, look up the jQuery library for `show()` / `hide()` functions.